# Nested Tracker.autorun() inside Meteor subscription. How to stop when component un-mounts

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I've got a Meteor subscription with 3 Tracker.autorun functions nested inside.

```
componentDidMount() {
  Meteor.subscribe('programs', => {
    this.myTracker1 = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      // reactive data source here
    });
    this.myTracker2 = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      // reactive data source
    });
    this.myTracker3 = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      // reactive data source
    }); 
  });
}
```

I'm killing the Trackers on unmounting:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.myTracker1.stop();
  this.myTracker2.stop();
  this.myTracker3.stop();
}
```

Is this all I would need to do when the component unmounts? Would the subscription still be running? Or should I just stop the subscription by itself, like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.mySubscription = Meteor.subscribe('programs', => {
    this.myTracker1 = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      ...
      ...
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.mySubscription.stop();
}
```

Would that stop all the Trackers? Would I need to stop the subscription and the Trackers separately?

I'm a little unsure after reading the Meteor documentation.

Comment: I'm confused what you are tying to do here can you give a bit more context? Normally you would have the subscription inside the Tracker.autorun so from my perspective you have it backwards.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Although it is working as expected. This component is rendering 3 cards on the screen with separate data, so in my case, each Tracker is listening to a subset of the subscription. The publication is a subset of the entire collection.